# Direct X-forwarding

Tags: 11.10, networking, remote-desktop, x11

I'm struggling to set up X-forwarding between 2 different machines on my local network and my ubuntu desktop. I'm able to connect using ssh x-forwarding one one machine, but the other machine (a Qnap TS-219P II) seems to have a less functional build of SSH on it, and I'd rather use a simpler approach.

I've set `$DISPLAY`, and done 'xauth list $DISPLAY' on the desktop, then 'xauth add ' on the remote machine.

From the remote machine, I just get

```
xterm
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: 192.168.0.4:0.0
```

Now, oddly, if I connect via `ssh -X`, there is a different magic cookie for the tunnelled port (but neither seems to work). I'm wondering if there is a port which needs to be enabled to permit X connections from the LAN? If so, how?

The proper solution might be to re-build all the packages which are preventing X-forwarding from working on my QNAP machine, but lets assume for the purposes of this question that I've tried building enough packages on that architecture already and want to run X without the overhead of encryption.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the X server on 192.168.0.4 is not being started with the `-nolisten tcp` flag that disables opening the TCP ports, and that port 6000 + *display number* (in your case, 6000 for display :0) is not blocked in a firewall along the network path.

Also, for ssh, check the `X11Forwarding` settings in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and `$HOME/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the definitive place to make the change in /etc/gdm/custom.conf

```
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
```

which should cause GDM to start the Xserver without the `-nolisten tcp` flag in Ubuntu.